# Try to Invoke a Function tru RTTI; Invalid Typecast

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to Invoke a Function from a Class (Object) at runtime.

The Object is found, the Method is found and the Parameters are stored in a TValue Array.

When `TRttiMetho.Invoke` is called, the following error is triggered

> Invalid Typecast

What is wrong?

…

```
    vcontext: TRTTIContext;
    vtype: TRttiType;
    vitype: TRttiInstanceType;
    vmethod: TRttiMethod;
    vparams: TArray<TRttiParameter>;
    vparam: array of TValue;

    begin
      vcontext := TRttiContext.Create;
      for vtype in vcontext.GetTypes do
      begin
        if (vtype.QualifiedName = 'somemodule.sometype') then // this is found
        begin
          if vtype.IsInstance then
          begin
            vitype := (vtype as TRttiInstanceType);
            for vmethod in vitype.GetMethods do
            begin
             if (vmethod.Name = 'Somefunction') then  // this is found
             begin
               vparams := vmethod.GetParameters;  // actually I know tha there are 2 Parameters
               SetLength(vparam, Length(vparams));
               vparam[0] := TValue.From(Ord(SomeEnum));
               vparam[1] := TValue.From<TSomeObject>(Object);
               vmethod.Invoke(vitype, vparam);    // Invalid Typecast here in
             end;
           end;
         end;
       end;
     end;
     vcontext.Free;
   end;
```

…

The error appears in `TRttiInstanceMethodEx.DispatchInvoke`, Line 5853:

```
    if (cls <> nil) and not cls.InheritsFrom(TRttiInstanceType(Parent).MetaclassType) then
      raise EInvalidCast.CreateRes(@SInvalidCast);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are calling Invoke with the wrong first parameter. If the method is a regular method, then you need to pass the instance of the object you are calling the method on. If it is a class method you need to pass the `TClass` of the method.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Rtti.TRttiMethod.Invoke) even explains it.

You are doing neither but passing `vitype` which is an instance of type `TRttiInstanceType`.